# Find file hash to match on Python and Java

Tags: java, python, php, hashcode

I need to confirm file download in Python by matching Hash values in both Python and PHP.
I get different value of SHA1 hash on python and java/php.
Also python3.5 and python2.7 also give different SHA1 hash for folowing code :

I am calculating the file hash value in python as follows :

```
 h = sha1()

    with open(filename,'rb') as file:

       chunk = 0
       while chunk != b'':
           chunk = file.read(1024)
           h.update(chunk)

    return h.hexdigest()
```

What is the correct way to match hash values between php (or Java) and python ?

Comment: Hashing works with bytes, so encoding should not matter. Post your other solutions

Comment: My understanding of Hashing was wrong.
I have updated the question.

Comment: For me your code works with both python3 and python2 and produces the same output as the `shasum` when used in binary mode (`-b` flag). Maybe there's a mistake in your php/java implementation?

Comment: I figured it out. There is a problem with the way I upload files to server. And hence there is a mismatch. Mismatch has nothing to do with SHA1 code. In fact the strict hash check helped find a more severe problem. Sorry for the trouble @hurlenko